# Enter Key function is not working correctly in MVC5?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I want to navigate from one field to another field by pressing enter Key in MVC5. So i used Enter Key function code.The code is mention below.

**My View**

```
 <form>
 <fieldset>
 <legend></legend>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
 @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })
     </div>
     </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alias, new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownList("SalutationID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alias)
     </div>
     </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
 @Html.Label("Customer Type", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownList("CustomerTypeID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })
    </div>
    </div>
 <hr style="width:100% ; align-self:baseline">
 <h3 style="color: #0000FF">Address</h3>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
 @Html.Label("Address Type", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownList("AddressTypeID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })
   </div>
   </div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group">
<span style="color: #f00">*</span>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Street, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text required" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Street)
    </div>
    </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text " })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location)
   </div>
   </div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Place, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Place, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Place)
    </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**My Jquery code**

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
 <script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJnj2nWoM86eU8Bq2G4lSNz3udIkZT4YY&sensor=false">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("form:not(.filter) :visible:enabled:first").focus();
 $('form > div').keypress(function(e) {
   debugger;
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
   $(this).next().children('div').children(":not(label)").focus();
   } else {
   $("form:not(.filter) :visible:enabled:first").focus();
    }
   }
 });
```

I tried this code. In this code it showing plugin error which is near to below plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
```

[image]

[image]

I tried many ways to remove this plugin error but  no use. please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Advance Thanks..

Comment: why would you want to use enter when tab does the job already? just set your tab indexes properly. Why create a solution for something that already exists?

Comment: Its is order from TL. Here this is one task

Comment: Id be inclined to kindly inform him/her that he/she is wasting your time....

Comment: I said but they use this function in another project so they ask me to do this in my module.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the jQuery is not initialized. Use it like this:

```
 $(function () {

$("form:not(.filter) :visible:enabled:first").focus();
 $('form > div').keypress(function(e) {
   debugger;
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
   $(this).next().children('div').children(":not(label)").focus();
   } else {
   $("form:not(.filter) :visible:enabled:first").focus();
    }
   }
 });

});
```

Notice that your entire javascript code should be encapsulated within

```
$(function () 
{ 
//Your javascript goes here 
});
```

The other problem I see is that your local javascript file "javascript.js" path is not correct. You will have to correct that to load your javascript file and get rid of the 404 errors. Same goes with the img.jpg file as well.

Comment: Ok i have a check Abey